# How to divide progressbar into segments at runtime as in tiktok while capturing a video?

Tags: android, progress, segment

I am adding progress bar to my application but I am not able to divide the progress bar into segments at runtime. Actually I am capturing the video then I start the progress bar and when I pause recording video the progress bar should get pause and after resume capturing video, the progress bar divide it into a segment and resume the progress from the last paused point,when video capturing is paused and resumed a white line should appear at the paused point [image: Like shown in image]

Comment: No need of dividing progressbar into segments simply get the duration of your video set it as max value of progress bar now when video paused get current duration set it to progress bar and here you go it will be done. 

I am just telling you the logic it's an easy task do not expect any code!

Happy Coding ;)

Comment: I hope it'll help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/23181240

Comment: @ViralPatel Thanks for your, I have tried this, this show progress for given time but I want to pause at any point and resume from that point and show the white mark at pause point , I hope you are clear with the image I have posted.

Comment: image too small. Can't see anything on it

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I think it is visible now, the progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the following repo:

```
https://github.com/muneikh/SegmentedProgressBar
```

Find the files here:

```
/progressbar/src/main/java/com/muneikh/
```

Add the Java files to your project and related XML.

Answer (score -2):

**In build.gradle (App level)**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.carlosmuvi:SegmentedProgressBar:0.8.1'}
```

**In build.gradle (project level)**

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
    ...
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
  }
}
```

**In your layout xml**

```
  <com.carlosmuvi.segmentedprogressbar.SegmentedProgressBar
  android:id="@+id/segmented_progressbar"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="5dp"
  app:container_color="@color/colorAccent"
  app:fill_color="@color/colorPrimary"
  app:gap_size="@dimen/progressbar_gap"
  app:segment_count="3"
  />
```

**in your activity class**

```
segmentedProgressBar = (SegmentedProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.segmented_progressbar);
// number of segments in your bar
segmentedProgressBar.setSegmentCount(7);
```

[REFRENCE](https://github.com/carlosmuvi/SegmentedProgressBar)

Comment: I'll try this, but I think we have to pre-define the count of segments, but I want  the segments can be of any number.

Comment: You can define segments dynamically on run time programmatically

Comment: link-only answers are always bad answers

Comment: @Vladyslav Matviienko happy now?